# Google Apps Scripts & Shared Contacts Access to a Google Apps for Education

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, google-apps-for-education

Does anyone know if there is a way to access the Shared Contacts on a Google Apps for Education (or Business for that matter) domain via Google Apps Scripts?  I am currently using the Shared Contacts script () to manage them but it is rather tedious.

We currently have 2 Google Apps Domains (one for staff and one for students).  The only way for staff to show up on the student domain is by adding the staff to the shared contacts on the student domain.  Likewise, the only way for students to show up on the staff domain is by adding the students to the shared contacts on the staff domain.

It would be great to be able to manage all of this via Google Spreadsheets and an apps script that runs once a day.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good post detailing how to do it in Apps Script - http://www.jellybend.com/2012/12/12/manage-google-apps-domain-shared-contacts-with-google-apps-script/

There are also a number of free applications that put a friendly user interface on this process, like FlashPanel - http://www.flashpanel.com/feature/shared-contacts/

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at that (quite) new domain [service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_domain)?

You can easily retrieve all users in one domain and add them as contact using the [contact service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_contacts) in the other domain. Then you just need to set up a trigger that runs the function every day to update the lists.

Comment: As far as I know, Contact Services gives you access to a user's contacts not the domains shared contacts.

Comment: And yes, I was planning on using the Domain Service to pull the users from the two different domains.

Comment: in Google apps for education a user can share his contacts with all members of the domain so I guess it should be possible to create a user (not belonging to a person) who's contact list is shared and add the other domain users to his contact list.  I never tried that in practice but I'll do since it could be useful in the domain in which I am ;-) thanks for the idea !

Comment: I'll have to try to find that feature.  It's not the ideal solution, but it might be a work around until Shared Contacts access is added to Apps Script or we switch over to a server that supports GADS.